# Where can I find winscard.lib for PC/SC programming in VC++ 2010 (Win seven)?

Tags: visual-c++, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc, winscard

I want to write a PC/SC application using VC++ 2010 in win7 x32 environment.
My program fails to compile with some linking error like this:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SCardReleaseContext@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl pscs_app(void)" (?pscs_app@@YAXXZ)
```

I guess that I need to include winscard.lib into my project, but I can't find it anywhere on my system. So I think I need to install something like a SDK or developer pack, but I can't find any suitable information about it on the web, can anybody help me please?

Comment: have you tried adding _Winscard.lib_ to the _Additional Dependencies_ list? From project _Properties_, _Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WINSCard.lib is included in microsoft windows SDK:

http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279